# Как получить ключи в словаре из файла в python?

Tags: python

[image: файл]

```
with open('test/mafiles/76561198156985244.mafile', 'r') as file:
    result = file.read()
    # secret_guard = {
    #     "steamid": result["SteamID"],
    #     "username":result["account_name"],
    #     "shared_secret":result["shared_secret"],
    #     "identity_secret": result["identity_secret"]
    # }
    print(result[0:50])
```

Если делаю таким образом, в result получаю строку а не словарь. Если вызываю print(result[0:50]), получаю 50 первых символов. Что нужно добавить, что бы в result записался словарь, что бы потом можно было получать значения ключей?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/appdividend.com/2022/01/27/python-json-to-dict/amp/

Comment: Вы что хотите-то? По уже известному ограниченному набору из 4х ключей составить словарь и в этот словарь занести значения, или брать файл и извлекать из него неизвестные ключи и их значения? А то вопрос у вас в теме "Как получить ключи?", а в тексте написано "получать значения ключей" (что не одно и то же).

Comment: есть файл "***.mafile". Мне нужно из него получить словарь и записать его в result, что бы потом из этого словаря брать ключи.

Comment: Спасибо за статью, помогла.